# ActiveRecord Reputation System related queries (has_many_through + polymorphic associations)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

### Problem

I'm building an application (Rails 4, mysql) to facilitate innovation tournaments, similar to the [Darwinator](http://www.darwinator.com/). I'm using [ActiveRecord Reputation System](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) as the rating system. I need to a JSON of the following format

```
results = 
{
  contributor_count: 51  /* (submitters UNION raters).count */
  opportunity_count: 100 /* total ideas submitted */
  vote_count: 250 /* total votes/ratings cast */
  opportunities: [  /* descending order of avg_rating */
    {avg_rating: 9.6, content: "vision"},
    {avg_rating: 9,   content: "favorite xkcd comic"},
    {avg_rating: 8,   content: "smash bro skill"},
    {avg_rating: 7.9, content: "programming proficiency"},
    {avg_rating: 7.1, content: "experience"},
    ...
  ] 
}
```

---

### User Story

Bob creates/starts the following tournament:

> "What is the most important characteristic in a CTO?"

Bob convinces 20 of his friends to submit a total of 100 ideas (opportunities):

> "vision", "favorite xkcd comic", "experience", "smash bro skill",
>   "programming proficiency", etc.

Bob then convinces 50 of his friends (including most of the idea submitters) to help him filter through the submissions (opportunities) by rating the submissions on a 1 - 10 scale. 

After 250 ratings have been performed on the 100 submitted opportunites (average of 2.5 ratings per opportunity), Bob clicks the "Finish Tournament" button, and is taken to the tournament result page

Bob is presented with the results of the tournament (see JSON above)

---

### Problems to be Solved

Result JSON:

1. contributor_count
2. opportunity_count
3. vote_count
4. opportunities in descending order of avg_rating

Rating Process

1. Randomly select an opportunity that the user has not rated/voted/evaluated
2. voted_on_count
3. remaining_to_vote_on_count

---

### Status / Updates

I will be updating this throughout my process of solving this problem. Look forward to additional information.

**contributor_count**: 
I can get submitters through @tournaments.users. I need to be able to the unique set of raters, then UNION the submitters with the raters... How can I get the unique set of raters?

**opportunity_count**: 
Freebie. @tournament.opportunities.count

**vote_count**:
Current strategy is to @tournament.opportunities.inject(0) {|sum, o| sum = sum + o.evaluators_for(:avg_ratings).count }

**opportunities in descending order of avg_rating**: 
Hmmm... some raw sql?

**Randomly select an opportunity that the user has not rated/voted/evaluated**: 
Using the [ramdumb gem](https://github.com/spilliton/randumb), @opportunity = @tournament.opportunities.random... but, need to filter out those that the user has not rated

**voted_on_count**: 
Related to the previous problem. @tournament.opportunities.where(has voted on this opportunity).count

**remaining_to_vote_on_count**: 
@tournament.opportunities.count - voted_on_count

---

### Models

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opportunities
  # submitters of
  has_many :users, through: :opportunities
  ...
end

class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :user

  has_reputation :avg_rating,
                 source: :user,
                 aggregated_by: :average
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opportunities
  has_many :tournaments, through: :opportunities
  has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source

  has_reputation :avg_rating,
                 source: {reputation: :avg_rating, of: :opportunities},
                 aggregated_by: :average
  ...
end
```

---

### schema.rb

```
create_table "tournaments", force: true do |t|
  t.boolean  "currently_running", default: true
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "description"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "opportunities", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "content"
  t.integer  "tournament_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "rs_evaluations", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "reputation_name"
  t.integer  "source_id"
  t.string   "source_type"
  t.integer  "target_id"
  t.string   "target_type"
  t.float    "value",           default: 0.0
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "rs_reputations", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "reputation_name"
  t.float    "value",           default: 0.0
  t.string   "aggregated_by"
  t.integer  "target_id"
  t.string   "target_type"
  t.boolean  "active",          default: true
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "rs_reputation_messages", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "sender_id"
  t.string   "sender_type"
  t.integer  "receiver_id"
  t.float    "weight",      default: 1.0
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```